# sum(case to calculate total euro per player

Tags: php, sql

Yesterday I started working on updating my scoreboard with some new colomns and got some good tips here so might I be so bold to ask another question?

Simple SQL here but I need the Case () as Euro summorized so it show total euros gained or lost over all rounds.

```js
SELECT  t1.playerid, sum(t1.points) as totalpoints, count(t1.playerid) as rounds,avg(points) as avgpoints
   
           ,Case
            when count(t1.playerid) in(7,6)   and (select points from pokermax_scores as t4 where t1.playerid=t4.playerid and t1.tournamentid=t4.tournamentid) = 38 then 15
            when count(t1.playerid) in(7,6,5) and (select points from pokermax_scores as t4 where t1.playerid=t4.playerid and t1.tournamentid=t4.tournamentid) = 25 then 5
            when count(t1.playerid) in(5,4)   and (select points from pokermax_scores as t4 where t1.playerid=t4.playerid and t1.tournamentid=t4.tournamentid) = 38 then 10
            when count(t1.playerid) = 7       and (select points from pokermax_scores as t4 where t1.playerid=t4.playerid and t1.tournamentid=t4.tournamentid) = 16 then 0
            when count(t1.playerid) = 4       and (select points from pokermax_scores as t4 where t1.playerid=t4.playerid and t1.tournamentid=t4.tournamentid) = 25 then 0
            else -5       
            End as Euro

FROM pokermax_scores as t1
group by t1.playerid
order by avgpoints desc
```

returns:
img "http://i62.tinypic.com/213iud0.png"

as you can see euros are not summorized but just random ones..

Comment: cleaned up the question so its easier to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution , first make a subsquery that gathers all info raw, then summorize this sum() in the main query.

example:

```html
select t3.playerid,sum(t3.Euro)
 from
 (
 
 select t2.playerid,t2.points,t2.tournamentid,
      Case
           when count(t1.playerid) in(7,6)   and t2.points = 38 then 15
           when count(t1.playerid) in(7,6,5) and t2.points = 25 then 5
           when count(t1.playerid) in(5,4)   and t2.points = 38 then 10
           when count(t1.playerid) = 7       and t2.points = 16 then 0
           when count(t1.playerid) = 4       and t2.points = 25 then 0
           else -5     
          End as Euro
 FROM pokermax_scores as t1, pokermax_scores as t2
 where t1.tournamentid = t2.tournamentid 
 group by t2.tournamentid, t2.playerid) as t3
 group by t3.playerid
```